# Combine excel and keep signature line

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sharepoint, digital-signature, sharepoint-2013

I'm doing an excel and SharePoint project where I provide user with an excel file with a Microsoft signature line that user review and sign. These are separate files for each user and the files are uploaded and maintained in SharePoint. At the end I need to combine all of the excel file into one long document that one person that review.

I found the following:

- VBA to combine multiple excel files into one file that has a tap for each file
- VBA to convert the excel file and it's tab into one long PDF

My issue is, when I combine the file or convert it it to PDF; the signature line disappears. Without the signature, it's hard to verify that someone has reviewed and signed the document. Is there any way to combine everything to one file and convert it to pdf but still maintain the original signatures in each individual file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to combine everything to one file and convert it to pdf but still maintain the original signatures in each individual file?

NO.

The signature can validate only that the original file was approved / signed, once you make any change (e.g. merge it with another document, or convert to any other format) the signature became invalid.